# ReactJS - trouble looping through data array props with map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

first time ReactJS user and am having issues looping through data I retrieved via AJAX to populate. I get a number of errors ranging from `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Am I supposed to be setting the props or a state?

```
var Posts = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
     return ({
        posts: []
     })
},

loadPosts: function(){
    var posts = null;
    axios.get('/getposts')
      .then(function (result) { 
        posts = result.data;    
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
},

postReadMode: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello, {this.props.posts.map(function(item, i){
                return item.title;
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

})

The data returned is somewhat of a multidimensional object/array:

```
Obj:
  0: 
     title: 'Title 1',
     date: '12-2-2015',
     content: 'asdf'
  1: 
     title: 'Title 2',
     date: '1-25-2016',
     content: 'asdfasdf'
```

Comment: You always SET state, you pass state as props.

Comment: In reactJS you set state using the `setState` method.  Try doing that, and it may solve your problem.

Comment: In addition, where you're using props, you should be using state in your render function.

Comment: So I did a `this.setState({posts : result.data});` inside the AJAX call, and then `{this.state.posts.map(function(item, i){ return item.title})}` with it returning a blank but I know the `result.data` have values in it

Comment: if you just leave this.state.posts without the map, do you see anything?

Comment: @deweyredman, no, it's blank as well

Comment: I think it's because you need to bind(this) to your callback...or create a closure outside of the function...

Comment: actually, crap. you haven't called loadPosts anywhere...

Comment: yeah, as the other user said, you can put it in componentDidMount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 points we need to be cleared:

- Using `{this.props.posts.map(..)` is incorrect. `posts` (in this case) is `state` because its value **is changed** (from `[]` to `AJAX response` after the AJAX request). You must use `{this.state.posts.map(...)` in `render` method.
- You should implement the AJAX call inside [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) method:

> If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place
>   to instantiate the network request.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    axios.get('/getposts')
        .then(function (result) { 
            self.setState({
                posts: result.data
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Set `setState` method will change the `posts` state value and therefore `render` method will run again to display new UI.

If you want a much better way to handle async networking stuff, give a try on [Redux AsyncActions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html).

Comment: Good catch, don't know how I missed that. Guess I was focused on everything else.